# Put an event on the model, or on the controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, mvp

This is for a client-side MVP program, using Passive View.

I want to allow the user to create a contact and add it to a quote. I want the quote to be notified when the contact is created.

Is it better to do a) or b)?

a) Listen to the model

Pass the contact to the contacts controller, and listen for a saved event on the model

```
var contact = new Contact()
contact.on('saved', function(contact){ do some stuff })

contactsController.create(contact)
```

contactsController then loads the contact into the view, user enters some info, hits save, contact is saved to the server, contact.saved event is fired

b) Listen to the controller

```
contactsController.on('saved', function(contact) { do some stuff })
contactsController.create()
```

contactsContoller then creates contact model, loads the contact into the view, user enters some info, hits save, contact is saved to the server, contactsController.saved event is fired

Thanks!

Comment: I don't want to officially answer this question but I'd say b), keep the model clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the subtle but important difference between wanting to know when a contact gets saved to the database versus wanting to know when a user submits the save contact page. I.e., the controller may not be the only place that saves a contact. If you want to know the former, use the model. If you want to know the latter, use the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following.

- User clicks Add a Contact
- The View tells the Presenter that a Contact as been added
- The Presents execute as Command that handles adding a contact

The Command does the following

- Displays a Dialog or View that allows the user to add the contacts.
- The Command waits until the user clicks add or OK to confirm the new contact
- The Command then updates the Model
- The Command tells the right Presenter* that a contact has been added.

Then in the Presenter that handles the Queries, the Update Contact call will find all the relevant Queries and update the contact info. This update may be done through a listener pattern where all the query views register themselves with the presenter.

*The right presenter is whatever presenter you setup to handle the view that displays the queries. Some system could have a unique presenter for displaying queries, in other it may be just be a part of a presenter where the query display is just a section of a larger display.